# Problem with `statsoc` class and pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, margins, document-classes

I am trying to use the statsoc class provided by the Journal of the Royal Statistical Society (JRSS). The class can be found here : [zip file](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1467-9868/homepage/stylefile16_new.zip)
I provide a minimal working example, which is extremely simple.

```
\documentclass{statsoc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title[Short title]{Long title}
\author[author short]{author long}


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keyword1 \and keyword2}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that, when I compile this simple document with `pdflatex`, I obtain a PDF document in which the text is shifted to the right, even over the right margin, see image attached to this post. I have the same issue when I try to compile the document with `latex` instead of `pdflatex`. [image]

What am I doing wrong ? What can I do to have a "good-looking" document ?

I am using TeXstudio 2.11.2.

Comment: The class is faulty. `\oddsidemargin` (and `\evensidemargin`)   is much too large.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your comment. Do you have an idea on how I could correct that ? Shall I just comment the lines where `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` are defined in the `.cls` file ?

Comment: I have no idea what geometry the class wants to achieve and which value should be corrected. If you really need to use the class, write the maintainer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class sets a different page size, namely width 17.3cm and height 24.7cm 
(actually 41pc and 58.5pc respectively), but doesn't pass correctly the parameters the PDF driver.

```
\documentclass{statsoc}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  textwidth=33pc,
  textheight=\dimexpr48\baselineskip+\topskip\relax,
  marginparsep=11pt,
  marginparwidth=107pt,
  footnotesep=6.65pt,
  headheight=9pt,
  headsep=9pt,
  footskip=30pt,
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title[Short title]{Long title}
\author[author short]{author long}


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keyword1 \and keyword2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to impose it on A4 paper,

```
\documentclass{statsoc}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\geometry{
  layoutheight=58.5pc,
  layoutwidth=41pc,
  textwidth=33pc,
  textheight=\dimexpr48\baselineskip+\topskip\relax,
  marginparsep=11pt,
  marginparwidth=107pt,
  footnotesep=6.65pt,
  headheight=9pt,
  headsep=9pt,
  footskip=30pt,
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title[Short title]{Long title}
\author[author short]{author long}


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keyword1 \and keyword2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` as line 2 of your `.tex` file and the file will render correctly.

```
\documentclass{statsoc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title[Short title]{Long title}
\author[author short]{author long}


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keyword1 \and keyword2}

\end{document}
```

[image]